# Memory issue while loading data

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, local-storage, amazon-redshift

Kindly help me while processing data which is fetched from redshift and processed in Python.

I want to use dask to store the data fetched from redshift to handle memory issue.
Please find the below code.

result = Cursor.fetchall()

Df= pd.DataFrame(results)

..instead of Pandas dataframe can I use Dask dataframe for same operation?

Any ideas/codes will be appreciated

Comment: What memory issue? You should remember that we don't know anything about your project or problems

Comment: Apologies, I meant while loading the data in Pandas, it runs out of memory, so as to tackle that I want to use DASK, kindly help..